# Get all agent hosts in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to find all the unique hosts that are producing data into ElasticSearch.  I'm fairly new to the ELK stack but I think this is equivalent to needing "all unique hosts across the entire fleet that have an agent installed on them".

I have tried

- `<instance>/_all/_search`

  - This does get the information I need (specifically the host info like IP, mac, OS, etc.)
  - However there are far too many results per host - presumably because each document relates to a particular, timestamped event.
  - I tried de=duping this data, but it feels like the wrong approach
- `<instance>/_nodes/_all`

  - I think this gives me each of the nodes in the server cluster itself, which is not what I want